# Sysprep Forever

Tags: windows, audit, sysprep

I want to use Windows in Audit Mode without continuing the Windows installation.

Because:

1. It's clean and fast, no Metro and others packages.
2. It's the built-in Administrator; full permission (elevated), no annoying UAC prompt and no fail of startup programs.

Question:

How to quit the Sysprep but keep in this mode?

Answer (score 4):

Once in audit mode, your PC will remain there [unless you run through the `sysprep /generalize` procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824920.aspx).

However, it is a bad idea to use Audit Mode for anything but initial testing and configuration:

1. it is unsupported
2. it does [break Windows Update](http://www.chris123nt.com/2014/02/15/windows-update-in-audit-mode-on-windows-8-1/)
3. it might break other things

In the end it appears much easier to just customize your station as desired after the install (i.e. disable UAC, disable Metro functionality, install Classic Shell) instead of messing around with an unsupported operation mode.

Comment: Don't forget you really shouldn't be running the system with the built-in administrator anyways. You're basically half way through the imaging process anyways, you might as well just set up the OS the way you want and image it.